# What exactly is a "Meth" in Altered Carbon?

Tags: plot-explanation, altered-carbon

In Altered Carbon, almost all characters refer to the ultra wealthy, powerful & famous as *"Meths"*.

What exactly is a *"Meth"*?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### Meths is short for Methuselahs

> Meths are essentially the richest of the rich, who have lived for a very long time because they can afford to continuously replace their sleeves.
>
> The term comes from the word **Methuselah**,
>
> In the Old Testament, Methuselah was the grandfather of Noah and the longest living person of all time.
>
> In the show, billionaire Laurens Bancroft (James Purefoy) is one of the oldest living people ever.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/916696/altered-carbon-what-is-meth-stack-explained-needlecasting)</sup>

From the novel it's explained as follows:

> "Bancroft’s not people, like you and me. He’s a fucking Meth.”
>
> “A Meth?”
>
> “Yeah. A Meth. *You know, and all the days of Methuselah were nine hundred sixty and nine years.* He’s old. I mean, really old.”
>
> <sup>*Altered Carbon* - Richard K. Morgan</sup>

Comment: "In the show, billionaire Laurens Bancroft (James Purefoy) is one of the oldest living people ever." Although technically, Kovacss almost as old.

Comment: Kovacs lost a couple of hundred years of his "life" if memory serves by being put on ice.

Comment: @Stephen, although technically, his personality was stored, and then re-sleeved.